# sudo apt-get -f install fails

Tags: apt

I think I have a problem with mixing different repository packages, but I can't uninstall any of the conflicting packages. Any suggestions?

```
gunnar@gunnar-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 107 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,151 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,337 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 247223 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/gnu', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64   2.19-0ubuntu6.5
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: if you're using x64 like i do, then you want try remove [libc6-dev-amd64](https://askubuntu.com/a/929919)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the observed behavior to be a manifestation of the following bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1365375

I provided a workaround in the above-cited bug report, in Comment #4:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1365375/comments/4

For your convenience, the text of that post is herein reproduced:

```
To follow-up on my previous comment, I was able to work around this "broken state" in aptitude by purging the offending packages with "--force-depends":

dpkg --purge --force-depends "gcc-multilib"
dpkg --purge --force-depends "lib32z1-dev"
dpkg --purge --force-depends "libc6-dev-x32"

Now, I'm able to use "apt-get" as normal.

Hopefully, this workaround won't cause problems in the future.
```

Unfortunately, the long-term solution is to await a proper fix from Canonical.

Comment: Thanks!  Tried all sorts of other stuff with no luck.  This fixed it for me so I can cross-compile on the new TravisCI Trusty workers

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file `/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb` and run `sudo apt-get -f install` again.

You have a 32 bit OS but have `libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb` file which is a 64 bit `.deb` file in your `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. So 32-bit Ubuntu is not being able to unpack it and giving the error. In a nutshell, run the following:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I removed the file as you suggested, but that didn't seem to solve the problem. The `sudo apt-get -f install` command seemed to reinstall it into the directory and I got the same error.
'After this operation, 6,337 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6-dev-i386 amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 [1,151 kB]
'

Comment: It looks like the amd64 is still getting reinstalled and causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

As `/usr/include/gnu` is being overwritten by file from other package, remove that package will solve your problem.

Run following command to get rid of this situation.

```
sudo apt-get purge libc6-dev-i386
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: So I tried that and got the same error. I also tried 'sudo apt-get purge libc6-dev-amd64 libc6-dev-i386' because these two packages are causing the issue, but after the auto remove, clean and install, I still get the same error.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/gnu', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb

Comment: can you post your complete output on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and provide us a link.