# Unmet dependencies libpng++-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, libpng

I try to (re)install `libpng++-dev`, but i got this error message:

```
 [...]
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng++-dev : Depends: libpng-dev
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to handle it like [Can't solve unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636236/cant-solve-unmet-dependencies)

But i couldn't solve the problem. Has anyone an idea?

Edit:
The output from  sudo apt-cache search libpng*:

```
libpng12-0 - PNG library - runtime
libpng12-dev - PNG library - development
fp-units-gfx - Free Pascal - graphics-library units dependency package
fp-units-gfx-3.0.0 - Free Pascal - graphics-library units
libpnetcdf-dev - Development files for the parallel netCDF library
libpnetcdf0d - Libraryfor reading and writing parallel NetCDF files
libpng++-dev - C++ interface to the PNG (Portable Network Graphics) library
libpng-sixlegs-java - Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder
libpng-sixlegs-java-doc - Documentation for Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder
libpng16-16 - PNG library - runtime (version 1.6)
libpng16-dev - PNG library - development (version 1.6)
libpng16-devtools - PNG library - tools (version 1.6)
libpng16-tools - PNG library - tools (version 1.6)
libpng3 - PNG library - runtime
libpnglite-dev - lightweight C library for loading and writing PNG images
pngquant - PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image optimising utility
ruby-oily-png - native mixin to speed up ChunkyPNG
tkpng - PNG photo image support to Tcl/Tk
```

Edit2:

Sorry, but now i got another error message (after compiling a c++ programm):

```
/usr/include/png++/reader.hpp:110: error: undefined reference to 'png_set_longjmp_fn'
```

Google said i should link against the right version from libpng but how can i do this?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-cache search libpng*`

Comment: output look above (Edit) - sry for the format

Comment: Install `libpng12-dev` then `libpng++-dev`

Comment: thx, now it workes!

Comment: Great ! I will post it as answer

Comment: Please uncheck my answer until you get the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo apt-cache search libpng*
```

sample output:

```
libpng12-0 - PNG library - runtime
libpng12-dev - PNG library - development
fp-units-gfx - Free Pascal - graphics-library units dependency package
fp-units-gfx-3.0.0 - Free Pascal - graphics-library units
libpnetcdf-dev - Development files for the parallel netCDF library
libpnetcdf0d - Libraryfor reading and writing parallel NetCDF files
libpng++-dev - C++ interface to the PNG (Portable Network Graphics) library
libpng-sixlegs-java - Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder
libpng-sixlegs-java-doc - Documentation for Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder
libpng16-16 - PNG library - runtime (version 1.6)
libpng16-dev - PNG library - development (version 1.6)
libpng16-devtools - PNG library - tools (version 1.6)
libpng16-tools - PNG library - tools (version 1.6)
libpng3 - PNG library - runtime
libpnglite-dev - lightweight C library for loading and writing PNG images
pngquant - PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image optimising utility
ruby-oily-png - native mixin to speed up ChunkyPNG
tkpng - PNG photo image support to Tcl/Tk
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt install libpng12-dev
sudo apt install libpng++-dev
```

**Edit**

The latest `libpng` can be download from here : [`libpng-1.6.26.tar.xz`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/1.6.26/) , install it as follows:

```
tar xvf libpng-1.6.26.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.6.26
./configure 
make check
make install
```

You can run `./configure --prefix=/path` , `path` = the path to the directory
where you want to install the binary