# There is the error that occurs whenever i try to download dependencies?

Tags: xubuntu

```
root@lap425:~# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 libwireshark3 libwiretap3 libwsutil3 re2c
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
 libc6-dev-i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
 libc6-dev-i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,152 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6-dev-i386 amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.13 [1,152 kB]
Fetched 1,152 kB in 2s (531 kB/s)        
(Reading database ... 322294 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.13) over (2.19-0ubuntu6.11) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.13_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/uio.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.13
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

solution for this.

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

The error says, that it cannot unpack the package `libc6-dev-i386`, because one file already exists from a different package and apt-get will not overwrite existing files.

> trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/uio.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.13

---

You can try deleting one of the offending packages:

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite --purge libc6-dev-i386
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite --purge libc6-dev-amd64
```

---

If both packages are needed by other software packages that you want to keep, you could try installing the new package and force overwriting files as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/56761/631600):

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libc6-dev-i386
```

Note: this may lead to problems with the first installed package.