# Broken apt, can't update libglvnd due to unmet dependencies (Nvidia)

Tags: apt, nvidia, 18.04, dependencies, budgie

I haven't installed any new packages recently or added any PPAs, just ran apt update.

**After running 'apt upgrade'**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglvnd-dev : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
                Depends: libglvnd-core-dev (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
                Depends: libegl1 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
                Depends: libgles2 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
                Depends: libgl1 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
                Depends: libglx0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
                Depends: libopengl0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**After running 'apt --fix-broken install' or 'apt-get install -f'**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgles1 libglvnd-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgles1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglvnd-dev
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/14.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 66.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 686678 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.106-0ubuntu3
Preparing to unpack .../libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglvnd-dev:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2) over (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.106-0ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried switching back to nouoveau temporarily but due to apt being messed up I can't. The control file asks for all the dependencies to be *-2.2 but when I try to upgrade it's asking for *-2.1.

**UPDATE**
I fixed it by running

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Same problem. Your recommendations is working for me.
But, libgles1_1 should be installed before ibglvnd-dev

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libglvnd/+bug/1791542 -- I'll be posting this in the other comment change as well.

Comment: Your solution works for me! You should post it as an answer and mark it, unless you think there's more to it.

Answer (score 8):

@pibacco solution on question worked for me:

> UPDATE I fixed it by running
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb 
> sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb 
> sudo apt -f install
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade
> ```

Comment: FWIW, you can put both file paths on one `--force-overwrite` command line. :)  I did just that with a `sudo apt update` before and a `sudo apt --fix-broken dist-upgrade` after, thinking that maybe fixing while installing the newest packages might not be a terrible idea.  Maximum variables FTW! :p

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove packages completely by

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends "libgles1" 
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends "libglvnd-dev"
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You can also see [Can't solve unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636236/cant-solve-unmet-dependencies) and [sudo apt-get -f install fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580232/sudo-apt-get-f-install-fails)

Comment: tried that, now I have unmet dependencies for
    libegl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev 
    libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev 
    libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev 

and apt-get install -f returns the same error as before

Comment: Purge "libegl1-mesa-dev", " libgles2-mesa-dev" these packages too.

Comment: did all that now i'm back to square one with egl1 and gles2 reinstalled and the initial two packages failing to process

Comment: now pretty much every apt command is returning `You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not installed
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not installed
 libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: Seconded - I also immediately run into things like SDL2, Glew, etc. that depend on Mesa, and I have quite a lot of time and work invested in some of these libraries. I may periodically uninstall all of these, get security upgrades, and reinstall them. (I'm considering a bounty, but I might not be able to use the accepted solution. Then again, my circumstances don't change the substance of the question, so I shouldn't post my own, right?)

Comment: Could I move the deb files actually causing the conflicts like `trying to overwrite ...libGLESv1_CM.so.1 which is also in package nvidia-340`?

Comment: I found a bug on Launchpad that appears to be this exact issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libglvnd/+bug/1791542